# Python BS4 not returning a Unicode value in find_all() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-requests, beautifulsoup

For a school project I wanted to write a python program which extracts the current value of Bitcoin from this website: http://www.coindesk.com/price/. To do that I installed the BeautifulSoup4 and Requests libraries in order to extract the HTML data and parse it but when it came time to actually get the price well, my program returns nothing. Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VHcP.png) of what I am trying to get. This is my code:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
doc = r.get("http://www.coindesk.com/price/")
soup = bs(doc.content, "html.parser")
price = soup.find_all("a", {"class":"bpiUSD"})
text = []
contents = []
for item in price:
    text.append(item.text)
for item in price:
    contents.append(item.contents)
print "text:", type(text[0])
print "contents:", type(contents[0])
print "text[0]:", text[0]
print "contents[0]", contents[0]
```

And this is the output:

```
text: <type 'unicode'>
contents: <type 'list'>
text[0]: 
contents[0] []
```

I used this way to get strings and number and it worked but when it came to this particular number well it returned nothing. Also, I know that the Bitcoin price is in Unicode (at least I assume this) and I tried to convert it into a string value but nothing worked despite the fact that the .type() function does mention that the list is Unicode.

Comment: price doesn't actually contain the price. check it by printing price right after it was made. price may be made by some javascript code so you may want to use something like Selenium webdriver

Comment: if you want to use request and bs4, you will have to find a different website

Comment: Wait so the value that I am looking for is generated by a separate javascript program? Sorry if my quest seems dumb but I am just a beginner.

Comment: Most likely. You could also try something like dryscrape

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to find a different website or use selenium webdriver. The price is generated by javascript that requests doesn't execute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

doc = r.get("http://www.coindesk.com/price/")
soup = bs(doc.content, "lxml")
price = soup.find_all(class_="currency-price")
print(price)
```

prints:

```
[<div class="currency-price">
<a class="bpiUSD" href="/price/" style="color:white;"></a>
</div>, <div class="currency-price">
<a class="bpiUSD" href="/price/" style="color:white;"></a>
</div>]
```

Which doesn't contain your number. If you inspect the html on your website it will have the number between the a tags. Using a library like selenium will allow you to run the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The website you are trying to parse with Beautiful soup is being rendered through javascript calls that are grabbing the data from an api publishing json rendition of the data, namely [coindesk api](http://api2.coindesk.com/site/headerdata.json?currency=BTC).  This is why your beautiful soup calls aren't working.

To get this data you need to make a request for the json using requests, then iterate to the data you need.

I went through the process for you in the below script.  I added notes so you can understand what I did in each section.  It could have done with less lines of code, but I thought this would help you better understand how to loop through the json.

This is in python 3, remove the brackets around the print statement if you want the output prettier in python2.7.

```
import requests
jsonurl = 'http://api2.coindesk.com/site/headerdata.json?currency=BTC'
json = requests.get(jsonurl).json()

for key, value in json.items():                     #Loop through the first branch of the json
    if type(value) == type(dict()):                 #each branch that has a dictionary is what contains the currency and rate
        for subKey, subValue in value.items():      #Loop through those dictionaries
            if type(subValue) == type(dict()):      #if there is a dictionary in this key value pair then we loop through them.
                for subKey1, subValue1 in subValue.items():     #Our final loop
                    if subKey1 == 'rate_float':                 #The rates are held in rate_float value in this key
                        print('exchange: ' + subKey, 'rate: ' +  str(subValue1)             )
```